# Gram Schmidt swapping two vectors of the basis

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, linear-programming, orthogonality, integer-programming

I'm trying to understand how the [LLL algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra%E2%80%93Lenstra%E2%80%93Lov%C3%A1sz_lattice_basis_reduction_algorithm) works and I've stumbled upon the following question:

Suppose I have $B = (b_1,\cdots,b_n)$ vectors and I perform Gram Schmidt process obtaining $(v_{1},\cdots,v_{n})$.

Now I'd like to swap position $i$ and $i+1$ in $(b_1,\cdots,b_n)$ resulting into performing Gram Schmidt process on $B' = (b_1,\cdots,b_{i+1},b_{i},\cdots, b_n)$. According to [this property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) of orthogonal transformation it should follow that $||v_{i}|| = ||v'_{i}||$ for each $i$, but the focus in my notes it that $||v_{i}||\cdot ||v_{i+1}|| = ||v'_{i}||\cdot||v'_{i+1}||$, which should trivially true since they are term by term equal.

What am I missing here? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The highlighted link goes to the page for Gram-Schmidt process, so I don't know what particular process you're referring to. But if we take $b_1=(1,0)$ and $b_2=(1,1)$, then Gram-Schmidt performed on $(b_1,b_2)$ will yield $v_1,v_2$ with $\|v_1\|=\|v_2\|=1$. But if we perform Gram-Schmidt with $(b_2,b_1)$, we will have $v_1'=b_2$ and $\|v_1'\|\neq 1$.

Comment: @user469053 The property of Orthogonal Matrices in "Properties"

Comment: @user469053 Ideed it seems that the matrix is not orthogonal. Do you know why the statement is true?

Comment: Orthogonal matrices have **orthonormal** columns, not just orthogonal columns.

Comment: I mean the statement about the product of those norms..

Comment: Because they're each just equal to the area of the same parallelogram.

Comment: You can do the calculation: Take $A,B$ and note that GS applied to $(A,B)$ yields $A,B-A\cdot  B \frac{A}{\|A\|^2}$ and GS applied to $(B,A)$ yields $B,A-A\cdot B\frac{B}{\|B\|^2}$. Directly calculate the products of the lengths.

Comment: The property you are referring to does not swap vectors.

Comment: @MarcDinh what is it?

Comment: LLL algorithm swaps two vectors. I guess the orthogonal property of the Wikipedia page you are referring to is $GS(g(v_1),\dots,g(v_k))=(g((GS(v_1,\dots,v_k))_1),\dots,g((GS(v_1,\dots,v_k))_k))$ which does not swap vectors.

Comment: Why swapping two vectors is not an orthogonal candidate $g$? @MarcDinh

Comment: The question should actually be: why would it be?

Comment: The associated matrix shouldn't be $(e_1,\cdots,e_{i+1},e_i\cdots,\cdots,e_n)$?

Comment: Just use your candidate transformation on the counter example given in the first comment to see if it works?